# How to convert data getting json object and string as well using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

From git There was a such a suggestion
but I don't know how to use it,where to call ,any tip could be useful
retrofit lets to convert json,xml ,but I need to have as a object,converted data and string as well

```
@GET("whatever")
Call<Pair<User, String>> whatever();

Type firstType = //reflection
Converter<ResponseBody, Object> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(firstType, annotations);
return new Converter<ResponseBody, Pair<Object, String>>() {


@Override public Pair<Object, String> convert(ResponseBody body) {
String string = body.string();
Object object = delegate.convert(ResponseBody.create(null, string));
return new Pair<>(object, string);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, checkout the [Retrofit documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) first. It's useful.

You can also go through [this](http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-parsing-json-using-retrofit/) tutorial. It's a little bit long, but it is good enough.

**All in all you need four things:**

- POJO (Plain Old Java Object) a.k.a Student, Car, User etc.
- REST client - check out the tutorial
- Interface where to describe each part of the API - check out the tutorial
- Wait for the callback from retrofit when you make a call to the API and do whatever you want with the info - check out the tutorial

Comment: I see it ,I go over it ,but it is not my case,it's standard case,while I need to have both datas

Answer (score 0):

If your @GET request is receiving something like that:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  "str": "Hello World"
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    @GET("/api/user/1")
    Call<ResponseBody> getMyObject();
}
```

Make the request:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://server.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
MyInterface service = retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);

service.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        String raw = response.body().string();
        MyObject object = new Gson().fromJson(raw, MyObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This simple case I know, I need to get not only parsed data, but also the string (raw data)
<Pair<User, String>>
how it should be implemented?
@A.Omar

Comment: I suggest you not to use Pair<> object.. Create your own object within a User object and a String, then receive it with the method above

Comment: But response.body() returns MyObject which include id and name. while I need the raw xml (before parsing) as well, maybe I'm missing smth in your code?

Comment: Oh okay, you have to use ResponseBody then. Just edited my answer!

Comment: In this case you receiver ResponseBody, and parse data in OnResponse()
like you are parsing your data to main thread.

Comment: You said you wanted both raw and object, you have them now... Anyway why do you even want the raw?

Comment: I need to store that data, for further use , and not requesting again from server.

Comment: It's not a different question ,I'm answering why I need to have raw data,I'm not asking how to store data

Comment: Your asking how to get raw data to save it next. You could simply serialize your object as it is in a file instead of getting the raw and save it. See gson library: http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/ OR jackson library: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/